# array declaration so lost on something so simple

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

Hey guys I have a very simple question but I will probably have trouble asking it. 
I am having trouble delcaring an array `Grocery[] item` in a class [but the size will be set in the application program] I think anyways, I need to send `Grocery[] item` as a parameter but have no idea how to declare it. I thought you always have to know the size? but I will not know the size until declared by the user, but that will not go in my class definition. please help!

Comment: need to see some code

Comment: How did you start teaching yourself Java graphic coding?

Comment: I didn't skip to graphics I was actually programming before I knew what it was. I started watching minecraft modding videoes, learn about programing, began trying to make a minecraft clone in java, failed, spent half a year learning, switched to C++, spent another half a year learning, wound up half-way between Java and C++, etc. The point is it isn't an imidiate thing. Sense I know that won't waver you I suggest you google lwjgl which is a java binding to OpenAL and OpenGL (audio and graphics respectively).

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ArrayList if the size is unknown at compile time. ArrayList uses an underlying array to store its objects so it has performance similar to an array.

For example, have your function accept `ArrayList<Grocery> groceryList` as a parameter.

Comment: How would I do it without using array list? and secondly why is array list so helpful I see it evertwhere

Comment: It is not possible with an array. The size of an array is constant and cannot be changed at runtime. You need to use a dynamic structure such as an ArrayList that can be resized at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't initialize it in your class definition. Only declare a class field of the array type.

And give the array as an argument to the constructor of that class and assign it in the constructor.

Or add a setter method.

No need to declare the size of the array in your class definition.

Comment: Well that my issue, this is my first time developing a class so I feel like it's the first program I have ever wrote, so I should just declare as followed....

Comment: @dgasdfdsfads yes. You should also read up on "java references".

Comment: should I declare it private or public?

Comment: Depends if you need encapsulation or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would get started by creating an array list, the code below can be used as an example to figure out your problem.

```
//Create an array list
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

// Add items to arrayList
list.add("Item1");
list.add("Item2");
list.add(2, "Item3"); // it will add Item3 to the third position of array list size
list.add("Item4");
```